# How do I use an array with an 'IN' condition on EntityFieldQuery::entityCondition?

Tags: entities, database

I read that [entityCondition should take an array](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3A%3AentityCondition/7), and I've constructed an array according to examples I've seen on the web. But no dice. I get the error below. If I use a string, the error goes away.

Here's my code:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$types = array('commerce_product', 'produce_share');
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', $types, 'IN');
$result = $query->execute();
```

And here's the error:

```
Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in entity_get_info() (line 7690 of /**/includes/common.inc).
Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in check_plain() (line 1573 of /**/includes/bootstrap.inc).
EntityFieldQueryException: Entity <em class="placeholder"></em> has no base table. in EntityFieldQuery->propertyQuery() (line 1209 of /**/includes/entity.inc).
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't commerce_product and product_share bundles not entity_type's (both of entity_type node)?

I think you may want:

```
// The types we're looking for.
$types = array('commerce_product', 'produce_share');

// Build the query.
$query = new EntityFieldQuery()

  // Looking for nodes.
  ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')

  // With the specific bundles.
  ->entityConditiion('bundle', $types, 'IN');

// Run the query.
$result = $query->execute();
```

https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708

Comment: Howdy. Thanks for the code! 'commerce_product' is an entity type, 'produce_share' is not. I had tried with a bunch of stuff before I posted. For instance, I tried it with `->entityCondition('entity_type', $types)` where `$types = array('comment', 'node');` These are undeniably entity types and I still get the error.

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer comes almost a year too late for you, but I dealt with the same problem and found out why the answer is you can't.

According to the [API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3A%3AentityCondition/7):

> While the field storage engine might support field conditions on more
>   than one entity type, there is no way to query across multiple entity
>   base tables by default.

Which means you can't query both the comment and node entity types with one entity field query because they derive from two separate database tables.

Simple Solution:  I performed two separate queries and concatenated the results together.